# Automated browsing with javascript?

Tags: javascript, automation

I'm trying to do some browser automation, but I'm having some problems. Basically, what I'd like to do is load a set pages, set some forms options, click a button and view the results for each page that I open. Originally, I tried to do this by placing the pages I wanted to automate in iframes and then using javascript to drive the interactions I want in each, but that results in a Permissions Error, since the sites I want to automate are not on my server. Is there any way around this? The other possibility I've thought of is to use QT's webkit class and the `evaluateJavaScript` method to accomplish what I'd like to do, but this seems a bit more heavy weight for something that is, conceptually, pretty simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tasks that I wanted to accomplish weren't really test related, so a lot of the test-frameworks don't fit the use case that I had in mind (I did try to use Selenium, but ran into problems). I ended up doing what I mentioned in original question and injecting javascript into pages through QT. This ended up working pretty well, although it was a pain to debug, since the javascript had to be passed in as a string and the base environment provided by QT's webkit class doesn't reveal a whole lot.

Comment: I just want to automate phantom js, but don't want a heavy solution like selinium.see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29751180/how-to-record-user-interactions-and-then-play-back-with-javascript

Comment: So I'm new to all this and want to do something similar, what's QT?

Answer (score 0):

Check out Selenium: http://seleniumhq.org/. It lets you automate Firefox and is probably the easiest to get start with.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do test automation? If so, there are plenty frameworks for that, like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/), [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/), [WebAii](http://www.artoftest.com) and even that built in Visual Studio.

Some of them (WebAii is my favorite) allow you to launch test in a real browser like FireFox.

If a peace of software you searching for is more like form filler, than take a look at [iMacros](http://www.iopus.com/), thay have a complete browser-side scriptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way of doing this would be to use a web debugging proxy and injecting javascript that way. This should allow you to debug the code you wrote within the browser.

I haven't personally used web debugging proxies, But I wrote my own proxy and did this a while ago just for fun and it worked great.